# <a target="main" issue in case of two different session

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, session

I have child window which has a hyperlink. On click of hyperlink i have to redirect to parent window. I could do this using following syntax-

```
<a target="main" href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/xyz/abc.jsp?id=123'/>
```

Suppose i have two parent window (P1 and P2) with two different session (S1 and S2 respectively) open. If i try to open child window from P2 and click on hyperlink, it redirects to P1 window. This behavior is very inconsistent. How can i ensure that hyperlink on each child window updates to their respective parent window ?